# how to get the popup window using TestStack.White and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm new to C# and TestStack.White,

The application that I'm testing (trying ....) is a WPF application.

I have a window that has a popup child-window, and I want to close it.

I have no AutomationId to those popup windows :(

I have the MainWindow and MainWindow.HasPopup() returns true :)

But I don't know to to get a list of (TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window)  from my MainWindow so I can do: 
Foreach _windItem ... _windItem .Close();

Thanks in advance !.

EyalS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a [Popup](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/WindowItems/Window.cs#L440) property on the Window. The [HasPopup](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/WindowItems/Window.cs#L455) is actually checking the popup property. I think a better way to do this would be to ask the application for all it's windows and then close all of them except the one that has a property that designates it as your main window. Here is an example in White for how to do this.

```
Application application = Application.Launch("Path to Application");
foreach (Window window in application.GetWindows())
{
    if (window.AutomationElement.Current.AutomationId == "MainWindow") continue;
    window.Close();
}
```

I also suggest looking into [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaU) because FlaUI's APIs make it alot easier to get at the information in the AutomationElement without having to add dependencies to the underlying framework that White is wrapping. Plus White has alot of properties which don't work the way you would think they would like the Popup property for instance.